# Optimize Long running update query

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have written following method with three sql queries in order to update a single column in a single table.since there are nearly 10000 records to be updated it takes more than 20 mins to complete.is there any other better way to do this updation.some thin like set based update...

```
private void UpdateLatest()
    {
        string connstr = "Data Source=CHAMARA-PC;Initial Catalog=PHPA_Production_fromEWP;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlTransaction myTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataTable DTT = new DataTable();

                string command = "select dh.DocumentNumber,max(dr.RevisionDate) as latestdate from " +
                  "tblDocumentHeader dh inner join tblDocumentRevision dr on dh.DocumentHeaderID=dr.DocumentHeaderID " +
                      "group by dh.DocumentNumber ";


                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, conn, myTransaction))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        adapt.Fill(dt);

                    }
                }
                label1.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int res = 0;
                        string query2 = "select dr.DocumentRevisionID from " +
                  "tblDocumentHeader dh inner join tblDocumentRevision dr on dh.DocumentHeaderID=dr.DocumentHeaderID " +
                  " where dh.DocumentNumber='" + item["DocumentNumber"].ToString().Trim() + "' and dr.RevisionDate='" + item["latestdate"].ToString().Trim() + "'";

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query2, conn, myTransaction))
                        {
                            using (SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter())
                            {
                                adapt.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                adapt.Fill(DTT);

                            }
                        }

                        foreach (DataRow Ritem in DTT.Rows)
                        {
                            string updatequery = "update tblDocumentRevision set LatestRev='latest' where DocumentRevisionID='" + Ritem["DocumentRevisionID"].ToString().Trim() + "'";

                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updatequery, conn, myTransaction))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                res++;

                            }
                        }
                        listBox1.Items.Add(item["DocumentNumber"].ToString() + " " + "updated");

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                myTransaction.Commit();
                MessageBox.Show("successfully updated");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                myTransaction.Rollback();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should **never** just concatenate together your SQL statement - you should **always** use a **parametrized query** instead! First of all, this will prevent SQL injection attacks, and second of all, if you have a parametrized query, that query plan will be determined **once** and then reused for all future updates. Your code right now causes a new UPDATE statement to be created for every single update, which needs to be parsed, query plan needs to be determined, and then it's used just one time... highly ineffective!

Comment: Also: since you're doing all selecting/updating on the database, why not wrap this up into a stored procedure and let it run **on the database** server itself?? Pulling down all that data to your client, just to send it back up to be updated is highly inefficient, too....

Comment: thanx for the reply!.actually here i'm not bothering about sql injection because the above method is not used in any commercial application.i have to use this method just to update the records in the table and that's it!

Comment: for the other reasons (reuse of query plan), I would **still** always use parametrized queries (or a stored proc on the server in the first place)!

Comment: yes! i'have also considered about writing a stored procedure and if i'm writing procedure i have to use sql cursor which is also cause slow execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your database at hand to test this, but basically, your code boils down to this:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (DocNumber INT, LatestDate DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Temp(DocNumber, LatestDate)
    SELECT 
        dh.DocumentNumber, MAX(dr.RevisionDate) 
    FROM 
        dbo.tblDocumentHeader dh 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.tblDocumentRevision dr ON dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID
    GROUP BY 
        dh.DocumentNumber

UPDATE 
    dbo.tblDocumentRevision 
SET 
    LatestRev = 'latest' 
FROM
    dbo.tblDocumentRevision dr
INNER JOIN
    dbo.tblDocumentHeader dh ON dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID 
INNER JOIN
    @Temp t ON dh.DocumentNumber = t.DocNumber AND dr.RevisionDate = t.LatestDate
```

This can be very easily wrapped in a stored procedure, it does **not** use any dead slow cursors, and it does **not** cause any SQL injection possibilities.

Comment: thank u very much.query completes less than in 10 seconds..ohhh.what i have done..

Answer (score 2):

> since there are nearly 10000 records to be updated it takes more than 20 mins to complete

Learn SQL.

Ok, first - 10.000 update statements = 20 minutes means your server is a laptop with a slow disc, not a database server. This is WAY too long. The way you do is horrific slow, but at the end... 20 minutes is way too slow. If this is a real database - get a server for it. You do less than 10 updates per second, even a normal desktop can handle about 75.

Now:

You do select then update. Why? Why not do

> update tblDocumentRevision set LatestRev='latest' where DocumentRevisionID IN (x,y,z)

and fire one off for every 100 or so documents? That brutally cuts down on the number of statements you issue.

On top if that is too sow you should fire them off async - prepare statement 2 while statement 1 executes, or even fire them off a number of worker threads in parallel.

And finally, SQL basics: is there an index on DocumentRevisionID?
And third there is no need to use an adapter and a dta table here. This is sloq, clunky and in general avoids proper programming practices.